# When checking if a piecewise function is differentiable, must one first check continuity?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

When checking if a piecewise function is differentiable at a point, must one first check that it is continious at that point?

The way I check if it is differentiable is test whether the one-sided limits of the definition of the derivative in that point is the same. However do I have to first check if it is continous (by testing the one-sided limits of the function is the same at that point)?

Comment: Yes, you must check continuity.  Consider a simple jump discontinuity.  The left-hand derivative may equal the right hand derivative at the point of the jump, but it would not be accurate to say that the derivative exists at that point.  If you have a removable discontinuity, it may be acceptable to repair it and say that the derivative does indeed exist.

Comment: It need not be necessary to check for continuity, but if the function is indeed discontinuous and you try to find the limit of the difference quotient, then this limit would not exist. Like, for jump discontinuity, $f(x)-f(x_0)$ may approach a non-zero number, while $x-x_0\to0$, so the limit of the fraction $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ does not exist (or is $\infty$).